# How do I get singular objects to agree with 2 possessive nouns?

Tags: grammar, agreement, possessive-pronouns

Which sentence below is grammatically correct and indicates that a driver damaged the engine in my car and the engine in my brother's car? (Different websites offer conflicting answers.)

A)  My brother and I had to replace the engine in our cars.
B)  My brother and I had to replace the engines in our cars.
C)  My brother and I had to replace our cars' engine.
D)  My brother and I had to replace our cars' engines.

Which sentence makes the most sense and doesn't imply that our cars have more than one engine? I realize I could re-write the sentence for better clarity, but I'm trying to understand the grammar. Thank you!

Comment: Please post the reference sites you mentioned. It might help your question.

Comment: Are we supposed to use "engines" in front of a noun? Or should it engine? Just a thought!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a particularly well settled question it seems. I recommend http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=286 which deals with a similar problem.

My personal tendency would be to go for:

> My brother and I had to replace the engines in our cars.

Comment: DRF, Thank you for the languagelog link. It's very informative (and funny). It does seem to lean in your opinion. Thank you to Rathony and Rohit for answering as well.